# Python - Print horizontally two strings, with |

Tags: python, string, printing, alignment

I'm having a small formatting issue that I can't seem to solve. I have some long strings, in the form of DNA sequences. I added each to a separate list, with the letters each an individual item in either list. They are of unequal length, so I appended "N's" to the shorter of the two.

Ex:

seq1 = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A']
seq2 = ['A', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'G']

seq2 became: ['A', 'T', 'G', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'N', 'N']

Currently, after comparing the letter in each list I get:

ATGG--G--

where '-' is a mismatch in the letters (includings "N's").

Ideally what I would like to print is:

```
  seq1  ATGGACGCA
        |||||||||
  seq2  ATGG--G--
```

I've been playing around with new line characters commas at the end of print statements, however I can't get it to work. I would like to print an identifier for each one on the same line as it's sequence.

Here's the function used to compare the two seqs:

```
def align_seqs(orf, query):
        orf_base = list(orf)
        query_base = list(query)

        if len(query_base) > len(orf_base):
                N = (len(query_base) - len(orf_base))
                for i in range(N):
                        orf_base.append("N")
        elif len(query_base) < len(orf_base):
                N = (len(orf_base) - len(query_base))
                for i in range(N):
                        query_base.append("N")
        align = []

        for i in range(0, len(orf_base)):
                if orf_base[i] == query_base[i]:
                        align.append(orf_base[i])
                else:
                        align.append("-")

        print ''.join(align)
```

At the present time, I'm just printing the "bottom" portion of what I want to print.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: To get pairs of characters, maybe you should use `zip(orf, query)` ? Then it would be much simpler to know what to print.

Comment: Is your issue with the strings being very long? (i.e. when it goes to a new line it doesn't work well?)

Comment: @Luigi, The strings are quite long. String 1 (after I shortened it to what it needs to be) is 1400 chars. String 2 is 1900 chars. Which is why I need to add the ends to string 1.

Comment: @GuillaumeLemaître I thought about zipping the two lists, after they were the same length, but then how do I print what is desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a solution for you that works with long strings:

```
s1 = 'ATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGG'
s2 = 'A-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGG'

#assumes both sequences are of same length (post-alignment)
def print_align(seq1, seq2, length):
    while len(seq1) > 0:
        print "seq1: " + seq1[:length-6]
        print "      " + '|'*len(seq1[:length-6])
        print "seq2: " + seq2[:length-6] + "\n"
        seq1 = seq1[length-6:]
        seq2 = seq2[length-6:]

print_align(s1, s2, 30)
```

The output is:

```
seq1: ATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGG
      ||||||||||||||||||||||||
seq2: A-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGG

seq1: ATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGG
      ||||||||||||||||||||||||
seq2: A-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGG

seq1: ATAAGGATAAGG
      ||||||||||||
seq2: A-AAGGA-AAGG
```

Which I believe is what you want. You can play around with the `length` parameter in order to get the lines to display properly (each line is cut off after reaching the length specified by that parameter). For example, if I call `print_align(s1, s2, 39)` I get:

```
seq1: ATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATA
      |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
seq2: A-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-A

seq1: AGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGGATAAGG
      |||||||||||||||||||||||||||
seq2: AGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGGA-AAGG
```

This will have a much more reasonable result when you try it with huge (>1000bp) sequences.

Note that the function takes two sequences *of the same length* as input, so this is just to print it nicely after you've done all the hard aligning work.

**P.S.** Generally in sequence alignment one only displays the bar `|` for *matching* nucleotides. The solution is pretty easy and you should be able to figure it out (if you have throuble though let me know).

Comment: Beautiful. A couple of spacing issues, but I can work those out inserting tabs when the "seq1" and "seq2" ID's change. I'm well aware of the use of the bar. I wanted to emulate the traditional BLAST output format with my alignment, and for at the moment, wanted to have a bar at every position for visualization purposes. Thank you, Luigi.

Comment: Just one question, qhy do you subtract 6 from the input length?

Comment: Because `'seq1: '` is 6 characters. That way the length is absolute

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a formatting question. I recommend looking at `str.format()`. Assuming you can get your sequences to strings (as you did with seq2 as align). Try:

```
seq1 = 'ATGGACGCA'
seq2 = 'ATGG--G--'

print(' seq1: {}\n       {}\n seq2: {}'.format(seq1, len(seq1)*'|', seq2))
```

A little hacky, but gets the job done. The arguments of format() replace the {}'s in order in the given string. I get:

```
 seq1: ATGGACGCA
       |||||||||
 seq2: ATGG--G--
```

Comment: I think the actual strings are too long for this option. I get both strings printed and in between (not lined up) are the "|"'s. It looks like I may need to split up the strings chars into chunks

Answer (score 1):

You could always try something simple like the following which does not assume the same size but you can adjust it as you see fit.

```
def printSequences(seq1, seq2):
    print('seq1',seq1)
    print('    ','|'*max(len(seq1),len(seq2)))
    print('seq2',seq2)
```

Comment: What about mismatches? That's where the '-' come in